# Hotel keycard switches on 5,000W load when placed in its holder. How does it do that?

Tags: switches, ac

In the hotel room I'm staying, I have to place the keycard in a holder by the door to power up all the electrical applliances in the room. Once turned on by the keycard, the circuit is powering the ar-conditioning, lights, power outlets, hair drier, switching a load of up to about 5,000W.

**What electronic device (transistor, triac, scr, relay) is swiching such a large AC load?**

Comment: Relays can take quite a load.

Comment: Out of curiousity: There is an RFID fob on the keychain?  Second curious question:  The cool/heat doesn't run in the room when you are gone?  That would suck, IMO.

Comment: Keychain? Or Key Card? A Picture might help, of both parts.

Comment: @mikeY Most of the time you can push in a piece of cardboard or a business card too, that keeps the airco running ;o)

Comment: @mikeY the cooling doesn't run when I'm gone. That's what prompted my question. I guess the manager wants to  maximize power economy.

Comment: @Passerby It's like jippie says, it's a keycard that only pushes a switch when it's inserted. A cardboard or business card would do the trick. But the air conditioning seems to be overdimensioned so that the room gets cool pretty quickly when I get in, even in Rio de Janeiro.

Comment: Just curious about the downvote. Is the question not appropriate to the EE.SE or does it lack research and effort? The question was just out of curiosity, really, but since user1410908 mentioned it, I know that such switching circuits can be simply made using relays.

Comment: I expect that the key sensor operates some relays (solid state or mechanical) to control everything.  If I was designing this, I'd switch the air conditioner controls, rather than switching the full power to the system.

Comment: @PeterBennett is exactly right. It's done using mechanical relays. The iSwitch mentioned in my answer below does indeed switch the air conditioning *controls* (via volt-free contact) rather than the 240 VAC power. It also incorporates a power relay for switching the ceiling lights.

Comment: @Ricardo the question does show a lack of research and vagueness. Keycard vs keychain as original listed, no model numbers or even pictures, which is asking us to guess at a possible method it is working by, which makes it open ended. If you said "How does Model X (part number: yyyzzz) Keycard Switch work? I have looked for a schematic or datasheet but can't find one. It does X, Y and Z" that would draw less negative attention.

Comment: You are allowed up to 5kW in a *hotel* room???

Comment: @radagast Actually, that was an overestimate that included 1,500W for the air-conditioning and 1,200W for the hair drier. Later I experienced first hand that it was all indeed overestimated, as the air conditioning alone took down the energy twice in my room yesterday. To sum up, the hotel electrical system is pretty bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keycard most likely operates a *contactor*, which is a power switch with auxiliary coil for remote open/close. A bit heavier built than a switching relay - the contactor is expected to carry much more current than a switching relay, and the design must account for this.

The construction and appearance of a contactor is comparable to a *miniature circuit breaker* (MCB). The difference is that an MCB is designed to break fault currents (10,000 A), but a contactor is only designed to break load current (~ 10A.)

No semiconductor electronics involved.

---

Typical contactors in the 4-40 A range are made by Schneider (i.e. Telemecanique, Square D, Clipsal), Sprecher & Schuh, and others.

In your application (domestic/commercial) you would be using single-phase AC power and thus a two-pole contactor.

Here are a few types:

[image]
[Telemecanique 2-pole 16A contactor GC1620M5](http://uk.farnell.com/schneider-electric-telemecanique/gc1620m5/contactor-2-pole-16a/dp/7160975) - 2-pole for switching of single phase AC loads. [Datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/77199.pdf). Comes in 16A, 25A, 40A, 63A, and 100A versions. This is probably the closest to what you have.

[image]
[Tesys K](http://www.schneider-electric.com/products/us/en/50400-contactors-and-starters/50430-iec-contactors-and-overload-relays/666-tesys-k-mini-contactors/) - 3/4 pole version for three-phase circuits

[image]
[Sprecher & Schuh CA8](http://www.sprecherschuh.com/products/contactors/ca8/) -  3/4 pole version for three-phase circuits

---

EDIT:

I remembered that my room on college used to be equipped with a magnetic keycard reader, which controlled the lights and air conditioning.

The particular device used was the [Enkoa iSwitch](http://www.enkoa.com/enkoa/de/energy-saver-hotel-iswitch-inteligente-basic-banda-magnetica-bm-2342.asp?cod=2342&nombre=2342&sesion=1347), magnetic stripe card reader model. The data on the magnetic stripe was particular to each room. (There were also RFID models.)

[image]

The datasheets don't seem to be available any more, but I had downloaded them a few years ago. The iSwitch appears to integrate two relays - one a power relay rated 10 A 240 VAC, for the room lights, and the second a volt-free contact, for signalling the air-conditioner controller. The wall socket-outlets were powered regardless of keycard.

The above information about contactors would apply when the keycard was required to control substantially more than 10 A of load.

[image]